# Predict Likert Type Classification Data in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

Currently, I am working on a dataset which classification class is a Likert type. Which is

```
1 = " Very Easy"  
2 = " Easy"  
3 =  " Neutral "  
4=  " Hard "  
5 = "Very Hard "
```

I create a multiple linear type regression model. Now I am trying to predict a class using my model. But the output is 3.45. So this result belongs to which class? 3 or 4. though it's a Likert type data it should be either 3 or 4. How can I convert this decimal value to Likert type data in R?

Here Is my code in R

```
dataset <- read.csv('survey.csv')
library(caTools)  
set.seed(123)
split = sample.split(dataset$difficulty, SplitRatio = .8)
training_set = subset(dataset, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(dataset, split == FALSE)
predict = data.frame(class = 3, nb.repeat = 1 , attendance = 3,
                 instr = 1, Q9 = 1,  Q16 = 4, Q17 =  5,
                 Q18 = 2,   Q26 =3,  Q22 = 3,Q5 = 5  )
demo_pred = predict(regressor, newdata = predict)
view(demo_pred)
```

Comment: Research from psychology shows that you shouldn't treat Likert scale values as *linear*, but only as *ordered*. The gaps are usually not of the same importance, so they shouldn't have the same linear spacing. So linear regression supposedly is not a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use ordered logistic regression, treating your dependent variable as ordinal instead of continuous. You can use the names of the categories and have the prediction come out as a set of categories. Have a look at this [link](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression).